# modifying windows 7 hosts file doesn't take effect

Tags: windows, dns, localhost, virtualhost

I'm trying to define some fake domains to point to `127.0.0.1`, but it does not take effect at all.
I edit `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.txt` (I know I should have administrator permissions, so the file gets modified correctly) and add for example `127.0.0.1 abcde.com` and save the changes, but when I ping this domain, it is pinging the corresponding server not my own machine. I also tried modifying the IP of existing domains in that file, but there is no changes.
I also tried to use some command like `ipconfig /flushdns` and also rebooted my Windows, but still working as before.
It seems like that there is another file or something like a presistent cache that prevents the changes take effect.

In this case, what should I do?

Comment: Please follow following URL
'http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/'

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: Have you read my question completely? I have clearly mentioned that I have done these simple steps, but there is another problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hosts file name in the question is wrong:

`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.txt`

-->

`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

Remove the txt extension. Note that this file should exists in your machine so just edit it.